# How can I "click" a button that performs a JS function through the Firefox web console?

Tags: javascript, html, web-console

My website somehow produced a rather interesting issue. We have individual pages for each auction that goes live, and this one in particular got messed up somehow. Typically we have an edit button that allows us to perform various functions, and one of them kills the auction.

**My question:** is there a way that I can manually enter that kill command into the console on the web browser?

The initial JS for the functions:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".remove_doc").click(function() {
        var doc_id = $(this).attr("title");
        var auction_id = $("#auction_id").val();
```

The "Kill Auction" command looks like this:

```
} else if(what == 'mark_dead') {
        var confirmKill = confirm("Are you sure you want to kill this auction?");
        if(confirmKill) {
            $.post("edit_auction.php", {id:auction_id, dead:1}, function(data) {
                if(data == 1) {
                    alert("You are now an auction murderer!");
                    location.reload(true);  
                } else {
                    alert("Failed murder attempt!");
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert("Your bullet missed..."); 
        }
```

Any thoughts on how I can run this operation in the console would help tremendously!

Thanks!

Comment: Run what exactly?

Comment: Why not just call your back end directly with the parameters?

Comment: I need to mark this auction dead so that it does not show up on the homepage anymore because it is affecting everything below it, but it is not showing the actual button. Somehow the page got messed up, and the auctions controls just show up as a blank text box.

Comment: So call the endpoint like I mentioned.... `$.post("edit_auction.php", {id:auction_id, dead:1})`

Answer (score 0):

You can try copying the lines of code that actually send the "kill auction" request to your server and see what happens.

By reading your code, the "kill auction" code is this:

```
 var auction_id = $("#auction_id").val();        
$.post("edit_auction.php", {id:auction_id, dead:1}, function(data) {
            if(data == 1) {
                alert("You are now an auction murderer!");
                location.reload(true);  
            } else {
                alert("Failed murder attempt!");
            }
        });
```

Try copying and pasting it on the console on the moment you want to kill the auction.

Comment: This looks exactly like what I was expecting, but it is not working. I'm also curious if there is a way I can track a JS event from another properly working "Kill Auction" button, and then apply that to this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your help on this!

I was able to figure it out. I just used bits and pieces from all of the advice. The JS command looks like this in the console

```
$.post("edit_auction.php", {id:1551, sold:1}, function(data) {
                if(data == 1) {
                    alert("Auction has been SOLD!");
                    location.reload(true);  
                } else {
                    alert("Error marking SOLD!?!");
                }
            });
```